# How to set different values for different material select using states in functional component of react

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, react-functional-component

I am new to react and using material design select box, 
https://material-ui.com/components/selects/

in the simple select box there is multiple select boxes available but when I select one select box option, all the remaining boxes set with the same selected value. 
below is the example 
https://codesandbox.io/s/yk15u

I want to set select box option value when I click on it. 
Provide appropriate solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the value separately, in the example provided all the `Select` is provided with prop `value={age}`. So all the fields point to same state for value.

1. Make the age state an object instead of string

```
const initialState = {
 select1: '',
 select2: '',
 ...
};
const [age, setAge] = React.useState(initialState);
```

2. Pass an id to handleChange in select and set the corresponding `value` from `ages` prop.

```
<Select
 labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
 id="demo-simple-select"
 value={ages.select1}
 onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'select1')}
>
....
</Select>
```

3. Setstate of `select` which triggered `handleChange`

```
const handleChange = (event, name) => {
  const newAge = {...age, [name]: event.tatget.value};
  setAge(newAge);
};
```